# MVC 6 Views only displaying white page

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

When I try to make a new view in an area in MVC 6 it only displays a white page.  The Home/Index action works fine, and this one will hit the controller but never displays the view.  I can return content and get a display, but when I try to return the view it breaks.  Any advice?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using PmData.Models;

// For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace PlantManagement.Areas.Cms.Controllers
{
    [Area("Cms")]
    public class AssetsController : Controller
    {
        // GET: /<controller>/
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

that is coupled with a blank view that calls to the main layout page.

Comment: You should always try to include some code, otherwise it is very hard to help you out. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I added the code I have in there... it's basically the default controller going to a blank Index.cshtml that calls to the main layout page by the _ViewStart.cshtml.  Like I said the Home/Index in that area works perfect.

Comment: Can you clarify: "... it breaks".

Comment: Yah, it gives me a plain white screen, nothing else.  Before I put the .cshtml page in the folder it gives me a 500 error (as it should), after I add the .cshtml file in place no more error, but it still will only display a white screen with no errors attached to it.

Comment: can you also include both Home/Index.cshtml and Assets/Index.cshtml in the code?

Comment: They're both blank views, no code on them.  They both are supposed to inherit the layout from _Layout.  Home/Index works as expected, Assets/Index only displays a white screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue.  Sadly, it's because I'm so new to MVC 6 / vNext so I feel silly.  It was a matter of their being an issue with an item on the page, but without app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); being added in the configure of startup.cs it would never show me the actual error, just give me the generic 500 error and white page.  Once I added that it started producing errors I could work with and gave me what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and resolved it by,

a) Create a _ViewStart.cshtml file in each area you have. i.e. Areas/Cms/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml

b) In this _ViewStart.cshtml file add

```
@{
     Layout = "~/Areas/Cms/Views/Shared/_LayoutCms.cshtml
 }
```

c) Add a _LayoutCms.cshtml to Areas/Cms/Views/Shared

d) In this file add the reference to the overall site layout

```
@{
     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml
 }
```

and any other area specific layout code.

That fixed my blank page issue. Hopefully yours too

In addition to my last answer, try these steps

e) Make sure you have an area registration setup within your Cms area folder i.e Areas/Cms/CmsAreaRegistration.cs

```
public class CmsAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
{
    public override string AreaName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return "Cms";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Cms_default",
            "Cms/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

f) In your App_Start/RouteConfig.cs make sure you are registering all areas by adding AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas() something like the following.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(); //Add this//

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id =     UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, sorry to go so long before a reply.  I tried this today (first real chance to).  When I added the layout on the page it actually produced the original 500 error on the console again.  I take it off and the error goes away again.  I can't help but believe it's the way the areas / routes are set up.

Comment: If it is an issue with the routing, make sure the area routing is properly configured. (Take a look at the edits I've added). Also double check that in your Cms area views has a web.config.

Comment: I didn't think web.configs were needed anymore in MVC6?